# FindContours() Compiler issues?

Tags: c++, opencv, crash

Recently I have moved a project from visual studios 2010 to 2012. As soon as I did I started experiencing memory exceptions that result from the use of findContours(). I've played around with other solutions, but none of them seem to be working. However, based on those solutions I believe that the problem is with the project properties. Any suggestions?

To be more specific, the code crashes with a memory heap error. Here is the code:

//cameraFeed is of type Mat and is declared earlier on.

```
Mat temp;
Mat HSV;
Mat threshold;

Vid_mtx.lock();
//convert frame from BGR to HSV colorspace
cvtColor(cameraFeed,HSV,COLOR_BGR2HSV);
Vid_mtx.unlock();
//track objects based on the HSV slider values.
inRange(HSV,Scalar(H_MIN,S_MIN,V_MIN),Scalar(H_MAX,S_MAX,V_MAX),threshold);
morphOps(threshold);
//if(calibrationMode==true) 
imshow(windowName2,threshold);


threshold.copyTo(temp);
//cvtColor(temp, temp_grey,COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
if(temp.empty()) printf("Whatcha doin?");
//these two vectors needed for output of findContours
vector< vector<Point> > contours;
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
//find contours of filtered image using openCV findContours function

findContours(temp,contours,hierarchy, CV_RETR_CCOMP,CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

Comment: Are you using the OpenCV binaries compiled with VS2012 or those which are compiled using VS2010?

Comment: I'm linking to the 2012 binaries (vc11).